# Emacs ESS indentation and auto-completion

Tags: r, emacs, ess

There are a number of useful variables to control <kbd>TAB</kbd> key indentation and completion  in Emacs (R) code chunks, when using ESS mode.

`ess-tab-complete-in-script` first indents lines and, if there is nothing to indent, autocompletes the word.

"With great power, comes great responsibility", so, when fast indenting your code, you might end up completing code without noticing with catastrophic results. Therefore you can refine things with the variable 
`ess-first-tab-never-complete`. For example: if `'unless-eol`, <kbd>TAB</kbd> completes only when cursor is at the end of the line; if `'symbol`, it completes also in the middle of a line, but not if you are in the middle of a word; etc (read doc for more
with <kbd>F1</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>`ess-first-tab-never-complete`).

The problem is that, at least for me, <kbd>TAB</kbd> is bound to `ess-noweb-indent-line`, but the command governing indent-or-complete behaviour is: `ess-indent-or-complete`. So I use to *fix* the tab binding with:

```
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook
 '(lambda()
    (local-set-key (kbd "<tab>") 'ess-indent-or-complete)
    ))
```

This works, but I wonder if this is the proper way. In the manual I don't see any prompt to hook to ESS mode and reset tab binding.

Do you know which is the canonical way to perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of reasonable ways to set the tab key (or any key, for that matter) for a specific mode.  The first you alluded to in your answer, by setting the key locally via a mode hook.  Note, though, that it's generally preferable to use a named function rather than a `lambda` so that you can remove the hook later if you want to do so:

```lisp
(defun ess-keys-hook ()
  "Put a bunch of keybindings in here."
  (local-set-key [tab] 'ess-indent-or-complete))

(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook 'ess-keys-hook)
```

The other option is to define the key in the relevant mode map, which you can do like so:

```
(define-key ess-mode-map [tab] 'ess-indent-or-complete)
```

Both ways are pretty commonly used, although my own preference is for the latter, as it strikes me as cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: When you mention removing the hook, do you mean setting `(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook nil)`, while keeping `ess-keys-hook` for a possible future need? Because otherwise I can always remove/replace the lambda function.

Comment: You would remove a hook with `(remove-hook 'ess-mode-hook 'ess-keys-hook)`.